# Finding the marginal PDF given the joint PDF

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Consider the joint pdf of $(X, Y)$ given by

$$f(x, y) = \begin{cases}
e^{-y} & \text{ if } 0 < x < y < \infty \\
0, & \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases} $$

> (a) Find the marginal PDF of $Y$
>
> (b) Find the conditional PDF of $X$ given $Y = y$
>
> (c) Find $\mathbb{E}[X \mid Y = y]$

**My attempt:**

(a)

$$f_{Y}(y) = \int_{0}^{y} e^{-y} \mathop{dx} $$

$$= xe^{-y} \big|_{0}^{y} \implies \boxed{f_{Y}(y) = \begin{cases} ye^{-y} & \text{ for } y > 0 \\
0 & \text{ otherwise } & 
\end{cases}}$$

(b)

$$f_{X\mid Y = y}(x, y) = \frac{f(x, y)}{f_{Y}(y)} = \frac{e^{-y}}{ye^{-y}} = \frac{1}{y} \implies \boxed{f_{X \mid Y = y}(x,y) = \begin{cases}
1/y & \text{ if } 0 < x < y < \infty \\
0 & \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}}$$

(c) Using what I have from (b),

$$\mathbb{E}[X \mid Y = y] = \int_{0}^{\infty} x \cdot \frac{1}{y} \mathop{dx} $$

$$= \left(\frac{x^2}{2y}\right)\Big|^{\infty}_{0} = \infty$$

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Remember that $x<y$

Comment: Oops. So the upper bound in expected value should be $y$. Is everything else correct?

Comment: The rest of your solution seems correct, yes